# Input tag dark color on top

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email address" style="width:290px;border-radius:5px;">
```

Pretty straightforward HTML code. Here is the JFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tLfpjL4a/

As you can see, part of the top is dark for some reason, not sure why.

I tried the following css features :

`border-style` and `border-color`

But it hasn't really worked

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't specifiy the full range of border options. Just add `border-style: solid` and you have a flat border.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `border` style:

```
.input-block-level {
  border: none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tLfpjL4a/1/)

If you prefer to use inline styles, simply add `border: none` to your code:

```
<input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" style="width:290px;border-radius:5px;border:none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `border: none;`:

```
input {
  border: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLfpjL4a/2/).

[CSS border property on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).

Answer (score 0):

`Border property` just note that it will take away all borders so you might want to set the properties else it will end up blank.So maybe something like this.

```
<input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" style="width:290px;border-radius:5px;border: 1px solid #B5B6B7;padding: 5px" />
```

I added padding just because it makes the input box look a littler nicer and UI friendly for users

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tLfpjL4a/5/

---

If you want, adding this:

```
* {
  outline: none;
}
```

Will remove that default browser outline that gets shown when things are active and selected on focus

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following CSS property for the input field.

> border-style: none

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

- `border: 0;`
- `border: none`
- `border:1px solid white;`

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tLfpjL4a/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

you have use class with border none.

```css
.input-block-level
{
  border:none;
}
```